# List files from App's internal storage to be able to load them - Android

Tags: android, list

I'm writing a relatively simple application for a college project that aims to allow a user to write notes, save them and then load them at a later time.

I've got the saving and loading sorted and it works perfectly (well, it seems to...) but I want to show a list to the user of all the notes in the internal storage (that they've saved previously) and allow them to load and delete them.

What would be the easiest way to go about this?

Thanks

Note: this is being built for Android 4.2 (API 17)

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out after more hours of Googling.

This page has a nice and simple answer for my question:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html

Thanks for the help though as it got me most of the way there.

Comment: Please note that this answer comes from the asker of the question themselves.  While it is briefer and more dependent on external references than we prefer here, deleting it would be counterproductive in that it would likely result in the question never getting an answer accepted, and so kicking around in limbo for years.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this task.

1. First store all the notes in SQLite DB in a simple format like **id,notes,time,isActive**.
   if you want to show them later, just write a query and get the cursor.
2. Store each notes in serialize object in SD card along with time stamp. and later load all the objects into list.

Comment: Hmmm. Not quite what I'm looking for. I'm using the FileOutputStream to save a file to the internal storage and then using the BufferedReader with the InputStreamReader to read the files back in. That bit works.

I want to be able to list all the files that I've created in this way and then be able to load them into another screen by clicking it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

First get the list of files what you saved in SD card, by using.

```
File fileList = new File("your folder path");
if (fileList != null){
File[] filenames = fileList.listFiles();
    for (File tmpf : filenames){
        //Do something with the files
    }
  }
}
```

And load this in a listview, clicking on each one , based on file name ,get the details.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to fill out the list with your help and some more Googling. I'm having a major issue getting something to happen when it's clicked though. From Googling it seems that what I want to use is the setOnClickListener function but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?